# How to create management.azure.acom api and do role assignment in Azure

Tags: azure, rest, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

How to create app for management.azure.acom api from scratch and do role assignment to customer to access subscription in azure?

Please provide examples explaining this scenario

Comment: Could you please tell me what is ```management.azure.acom api from scratch ```? Is it Azure rest api?

Comment: yes it is a azure rest api

Comment: Please refer to https://abcdazure.azurewebsites.net/how-to-authenticate-in-azure-rest-api/

Comment: Have you checked my answer? If it helps, you may mark it as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in app for getting access token to call Azure REST API.

What you need:

- Azure admin account
- Subscription ID
- Tenant ID or name

### 1. Get token for AD Graph REST API

```
POST  https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your_tenant_id_or_name}/oauth2/token

Headers
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body
grant_type=password
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net%2F
&client_id=1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2
&username={your_user_name}
&password={your_password}
```

Then you will get an access token in response:

[image]

### 2. [Get user object ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#get-users--)

Use `$filter` expression to get the target user information, for example:

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/{tenant_id}/users?$filter=userPrincipalName%20eq%20'jack%40hanxia.onmicrosoft.com'&api-version=1.6 

Headers
Authorization: Bearer {access_token_you_get_in_step_1}
```

Then you will get the user's object ID in response:

[image]

### 3. Get token for Azure Management API

```
POST  https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your_tenant_id_or_name}/oauth2/token

Headers
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body
resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F
&client_id=1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2
&grant_type=password
&username={your_user_name}
&password={your_password}
&scope=openid
```

Then you will get an access token in response.

### 4. Get Role ID

Here, I will try to get the role ID of `Owner` by using `$filter` expression:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{your_subscription_id}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions?$filter=roleName%20eq%20'Owner'&api-version=2018-01-01-preview 

Headers
Authorization: Bearer {access_token_you_get_in_step_3}
```

Then you will get the role ID in response:

[image]

### 5. Add role assignment

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{your_subscription_id}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/{a_new_guid}?api-version=2018-09-01-preview 

Headers
Authorization: Bearer {access_token_you_get_in_step_3}
Content-Type: application/json

Body
{
  "properties": {
    "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/e5b0fcfa-e859-43f3-8d84-5e5fe29f4c68/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635",
    "principalId": "ab6d4cd6-fc2d-40c7-a676-f8773aebfb5f"
  }
}
```

`roleDefinitionId` is the role ID which I get in step 4, `principalId` is the user object ID which I get in step 2.

---

It would be much easier to use Azure PowerShell or Azure CLI to do the role assignment:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Subscription "your_subscription_id"

# to whole subscription
New-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName "user@****.onmicrosoft.com" -RoleDefinitionName "Owner"

# to a specific resource group
New-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName "user@****.onmicrosoft.com" -RoleDefinitionName "Owner" -ResourceGroupName "resource_group_name"
```